# Django Static Finders Search Path

Tags: django

One of the default Django static finder is

django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder, question is where does

Django search for using this default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docstring](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py#L45//) for `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder` describes `FileSystemFinder` as follows:

> A static files finder that uses the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting
>     to locate files.

So it uses the value of [`STATICFILE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) in settings.py, which is a list of string directory paths (which should be Unix-style paths even on windows). This is useful if you have additional static files in various locations other than your apps.

Comment: just for clarification STATIC_DIRS files goes to STATIC_ROOt location.  So I think you mean additional static files in locations other than in apps.  In any case why would I collect static files in STATIC_ROOT location when it is not used in production deployment?

Comment: @djangog As far as I know `STATICFILE_DIRS` **does not** go to `STATIC_ROOT` unless you explicitly tell it too. By default it is an empty list.

Comment: @djangog Also, I have never heard that you should not collect static files from `STATIC_ROOT` in production. This is what I do in production. Either way, I am not making any comment as to where you should store your static files or how you should locate them, I am simply trying to answer your question based on what the Django docs and source themselves have to say.

Comment: you are correct " STATICFILE_DIRS does not go to STATIC_ROOT unless you explicitly tell it too". Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @djangog I was mistaken about `STATIC_ROOT`: I was thinking it was the place where static files are collected *from* not collected *to*. Thanks for correcting that mistake. I have updated my answer.